# Interval of the solutions to $\log_{1/2}\log_2(\frac{1+2x}{1+x})>0$ is?

Tags: logarithms

I consistently get $x>-1$ but that doesn't fit the possible solutions I've got.

First step I do is state that $\log_2(\frac{1+2x}{1+x})<1$

Then express the $1$ as $\log_22$ and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the followings as well : 
$$\log_2\left(\frac{1+2x}{1+x}\right)\gt 0\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \frac{1+2x}{1+x}\gt 0,$$
i.e.
$$\frac{1+2x}{1+x}\gt 1.$$

Hence, the answer will be $$x\gt -1\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \frac{1+2x}{1+x}\gt 1,$$
i.e.
$$x\gt 0.$$